# PHP Special chars escape

Tags: php, character-encoding, http-status-code-500

I have a password with special chars in my php file.
The original String returns a 500 html error code.
The following chars are the root cause.

`()[]$`

The line of code is:
`private $password = "abc(de)fgh[ijk]lmn$opq$";`

How can I correctly escape those chars?
I have tried to replace them with the HTML charset, as well as `\\`

Comment: Why not just use single-quotes (since the string doesn't need to be parsed by php)? Then you'd only need to escape any single-quotes in your string by using `\`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are the simplest way to make a string. They just display what they are given, no bells and whistles, no special "powers" like being able to show variable values.

Use Single quotes.

Comment: Just add an additional point that if it's so necessary to use double quotes, they can just escape them with a \. https://3v4l.org/pSFCd